# Codestyling-localization Wordpress plugin can't detect my theme

Tags: localization, wordpress

I use codestyling-localization plugin in my wordpress theme to edit the locale files. In my theme I tried all of the following:

*functions.php:*

```
<?php

/**
 * Text Domain: my_locale
 * Domain Path: /languages
 */
function my_theme_setup() {
    var_dump(load_theme_textdomain('my_locale', TEMPLATEPATH . '/languages'));
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_setup');
```

*style.css:*

```
/*
Textdomain:  my_locale
Domain Path: /languages
*/
```

I created files under `languages/`: `cs_CZ.mo` and `en_US.mo`.

But the plugin still can't find the languages. However, the `var_dump` method in `my_theme_setup` returns true. I have no idea what is wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I digged into the plugin and found out that it won't process themes marked as "with errors". A feature, which is probably not desired.